# VSTO Outlook: Get last email address just entered in the "To", "Bc" or "Cc" fields in new, reply or forward windows

Tags: email, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am trying to get the last recipient (email address) just introduced into the "To", "Bc" or "Cc" fields when field loses its focus. How can I achieve this?

For example:

- if user just types in an email address within "To" field I want to get that.
- if user just types in an email address within "Bc" field I want to get that.
- if user just types in an email address within "Cc" field I want to get that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MailItem.PropertyChange` event. Whenever any recipient is changed (added/deleted), the event handler fires for all 3 (To/CC/BCC) properties, so your won't know which one changed. You'd need to cache the old value first, and when the event fires, compare it with new value.

```
PropertyChange ("To")
PropertyChange ("CC")
PropertyChange ("BCC")
```

Comment: Why VSTO Outlook technology is so limited?

Comment: It is not really VSTO, but rather the Outlook Object Model - if you think OOM is limited, try to deal the new JS web addins :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the [MailItem.PropertyChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.propertychange) event which is fired when an explicit built-in property (for example, `Subject`) of the object is changed. The property name is passed to the event so that you can determine which property was changed.

The `Recipients` property returns a [Recipients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients) collection that represents all the recipients for the Outlook item. So, you could get easily get the items for the To, Cc or Bcc fields.